# Netezza: How to add a column to a table

Tags: netezza

ALTER TABLE table_name ADD column is not supported. Are there any other ways to add a column to a table?

Comment: If you don't have access to your Database Users Guide, it's online too: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.1.0/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_ntz_sql_command_reference.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're quite wrong. Netezza supports adding columns. This is described in your Database Users Guide, B-19 section explains the ALTER TABLE syntax.

See the output from nzsql:

```
LABDB(ADMIN)=> CREATE TABLE REGION2 AS SELECT * FROM REGION;
INSERT 0 4
Elapsed time: 0m0.138s
LABDB(ADMIN)=> ALTER TABLE REGION2 ADD r_col1 char(8);
ALTER TABLE
Elapsed time: 0m0.145s
LABDB(ADMIN)=> SELECT * FROM REGION2;
 R_REGIONKEY |          R_NAME           |          R_COMMENT          | R_COL1
-------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------+--------
           4 | ap                        | asia pacific                |
           3 | emea                      | europe, middle east, africa |
           2 | sa                        | south america               |
           1 | na                        | north america               |
(4 rows)

Elapsed time: 0m0.510s
LABDB(ADMIN)=> UPDATE REGION2 SET r_col1 = 'AABBAABB';
UPDATE 4
Elapsed time: 0m1.256s
LABDB(ADMIN)=> SELECT * FROM REGION2;
 R_REGIONKEY |          R_NAME           |          R_COMMENT          |  R_COL1
-------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------+----------
           1 | na                        | north america               | AABBAABB
           3 | emea                      | europe, middle east, africa | AABBAABB
           4 | ap                        | asia pacific                | AABBAABB
           2 | sa                        | south america               | AABBAABB
(4 rows)

Elapsed time: 0m0.111s
LABDB(ADMIN)=>
```